# Showing Images filter on encrypted Google search

Tags: google-search, google-image-search

When I use [Google Encrypted](https://encrypted.google.com/) sometimes I can't see **Images** in the left panel (even if I click on More).

How do I make it show?

Answer (score 1):

It's not showing as an option since they haven't yet made that available in an SSL version.

> #### [Features: SSL Search](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173733)
>
> Note that only Google web search is available over SSL, so other search products like Google Images and Google Maps are not currently available over SSL.

When you're searching you should still see an option for Google Images in the main results section if there are any relevant matches. However, clicking through will drop you out of the encrypted Google search and you'll be back in the regular version.

Comment: I can't understand their ` if there are any relevant matches` algorithm. Many queries that obviously has relevant matches don't trigger the option.